# Semantic-UI-React: Card header with 2 columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want the card header to be the normal text together with an image, side by side.

```
  import logo from './images/logo.svg';

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
          <Card.Content className='left aligned'>
            <div className="two column headers">
              <Card.Header>Hello World!</Card.Header>
              <Image src={logo} size='tiny'/>
            </div>
            <Card.Meta>Item</Card.Meta>
            <Card.Meta>Category</Card.Meta>
          </Card.Content>

          <Card.Content>
            <Card.Description>10 units of test.</Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>    
     </div>
    );
```

The image is appearing just after the **'Hello World!'** header. How can I put them side by side, left aliging the text and right aligning the image ?
[image: Real image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS, however I will recomend to use Grid there.

```
<Card.Header>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Column width={12}>Hello World!</Grid.Column>                
    <Grid.Column width={4}>
      <Image src={logo} size='tiny'/>
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid>
</Card.Header>
```

By the way, if you want to have an Image component on left, you can use Header component, see [examples](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/header#header-example-image).